# How to change the width of UIkit.notification?

Tags: getuikit

On the [getuikit](https://getuikit.com/) web library, how can I change the width of the notification?

```
UIkit.notification({message: 'Primary message...', status: 'primary'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no programmatic way as far as I know, but you can use CSS to make the notification wider. Depending on the alignment of the notification, you will also need to adjust positioning to reflect new width (here notification is 600px, margin-left is half of it, so -300px)

```js
UIkit.notification({message: 'Primary message ...', status: 'primary', timeout: 60000});

UIkit.notification({message: 'Another short ...', status: 'primary', timeout: 60000});

UIkit.notification({message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.', status: 'primary', timeout: 60000});
```

```css
.uk-notification {
  width: 100%!important;
  display: flex!important;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.uk-notification-message {
  padding-right: 2em!important;
  width: auto!important;
  max-width: 70%!important;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.uk-notification-top-center,
.uk-notification-top-left,
.uk-notification-top-right {
  margin: 0!important;
  left: unset!important;
  text-align: center;
}
.uk-notification-top-center > .uk-notification-message {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}
.uk-notification-top-left > .uk-notification-message {
  margin: 10px auto 0 10px;
}
.uk-notification-top-right > .uk-notification-message {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>



<p uk-margin>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default demo" type="button" onclick="UIkit.notification({message: 'Right align ...', status: 'primary', timeout: 60000, pos: 'top-right'})">Right text</button>
    
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default demo" type="button" onclick="UIkit.notification({message: 'Left align ...', status: 'primary', timeout: 60000, pos: 'top-left'})">Left text</button>

    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default demo" type="button" onclick="UIkit.notification({message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.', status: 'primary', timeout: 60000})">Long text</button>
</p>
```

Comment: is it possible to use the width of content with a max width? I tried the following, but it does not work: `.uk-notification{
    width: unset!important;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    max-width: 70%!important;
}
.uk-notification-top-center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
`

Comment: looks great! only problem, clicking the "short text" button twice, the second notification appears on the right of the first one, instead of below it.

Comment: OK, rewritten with flexbox and auto opening 3 notifications for demonstration ;)

Comment: thanks @moped! but this seems like an art and quite esoteric; this pop appears now on the center (instead of on the right), overlapping other messages: `UIkit.notification({message: 'my-message-right!', pos: 'top-right'});`

Comment: it's just playing with alignment as it is not aligned using flexbox. would be much easier if it's not `position:fixed`, but it's a notification so it needs to be like this (I don't know other/better way). have a look at the snippet, align left center right added..